# Does vkCmdCopyImage automatically convert tiling property?

Tags: memory-management, vulkan

I have read a spec of `vkCmdCopyImage` and I saw that only element size is required to match in both way. I wonder if we can copy an image with optimal tiling (src) to a linear tiling one (dst). Is the dst one gonna have linear tiling and be usable? By assuming that the two images have the same format.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`vkCmdCopyImage` copies texels (not bytes). Tiling is an addressing matter which should be hidden by the abstraction of a texel.
Furthermore, it is not forbidden by the Valid Usage.
So, yes; it does.

We had an extended discussion [on the Vulkan forum](https://forums.khronos.org/showthread.php/13032-Reading-depth-image-memory-from-host).

Also the Vulkan Specification is open on [KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs). You can post an Issue or propose a change directly as PR.
If you read the spec directly, and despite your best efforts the matter is still not clear, then it **is** probably not specified well enough and others can get equally confused (and start making buggy drivers and apps). It is in everyones benefit to communicate with the authors directly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can copy data from images with optimal tiling to those with linear tiling and vice versa. Appropriate tiling conversion is done automatically. This is one of the methods to upload data to (or copy data from) optimally tiled images as those cannot be mapped directly (well, they *can* be mapped but we don't know how their contents are laid out so mapping them makes very little, if no at all, sense). When we transfer data through linearly tiled resources we call these **staging resources**. And for those we can use not only images but also buffers. Many people (including me) claim using buffers is more preferable, because they are always linear, they don't need layout transitions and they are easier to create (create info has less parameters). `vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer` (or the other way round) does all the necessary transformation for You (though no format conversion).

Intel has a tutorial about [staging resources](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/api-without-secrets-introduction-to-vulkan-part-5) and a another one in which staging buffer is used to [upload data to an optimally tiled image](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/api-without-secrets-introduction-to-vulkan-part-6). The mechanism is the same as with linearly tiled images and works in both ways.

Comment: Thank you. I've been using vkCmdCopyImage to grab screenshots, but discovered it doesn't like it when my window size is not a multiple of 8. This should sort it out as vkCmdCopyBufferToImage has been working nicely for me the other way (not sure why I used vkCmdCopyImage in the first place)